# Yii 2 - Difference between using $_POST and Yii::$app->request->post()

Tags: php, post, yii

I am learning Yii from a book (Web Application Development with Yii 2 and PHP). I come across a code as follows:

```
if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {...}
```

But this code **seems to** function equally:

```
if ($model->load($_POST && $model->save()) {...}
```

So is there any practical difference between using two?

Comment: For one thing, testing your app is easier when you can build a request object and tell the framework to "run this request" instead of manually fudging `$_GET`, `$_POST` and all the other superglobals.

Comment: Could you be so kind to provide an example?

Comment: Testing is a very broad topic, you'll need to do some research yourself. For example, Symfony does functional testing like this: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/testing.html#functional-tests - that code simulates a visitor opening a page on your site, runs the appropriate controller/action, and lets you test the response. Yii documentation also tells you to use the `->request` approach for the same reason: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-runtime-requests.html

Comment: OK, reading the pages provided, it is more clear now. Thank you very much. If you can add it as an answer, I can accept it. If that matters for you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One important reason to use the `request` object is *testability*:

Functional tests that exercise your controller actions should be a part of your test suite. For simple scenarios like "if I open the `/event/calendar` page, I get a list of events", you can create mock requests, ask the framework to handle them, and inspect the result¹. You *could* do this testing by assigning values directly to `$_GET`, `$_POST`, and other superglobals... but using a framework's `request` object is much easier and the frameworks generally have good support for this scenario.

For example:

- Yii 2 documentation recommends this approach: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-runtime-requests.html
- Symfony documentation has examples of such tests: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/testing.html#functional-tests

---

¹: For more complex scenarios that involve user interactions, this will not be enough, you will need a tool like Selenium: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/test.functional